# How to show that the random variable is finite almost everywhere?

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

Random variables $X_1$, $\ldots$, $X_n$ are independent and each of them has uniform distribution on interval $(0,1)$. We define
$$ T=\inf \{ n: X_1+\ldots+X_n\geq 1\}.  $$
I managed to evaluate the distibution of $T$. Namely
$$ P(T>k)=\dfrac{1^k}{k!}   . $$

Anyway, I have a problem with showing that $T$ is finite almost everywhere.
I have found that the function is finite almost everywhere when it is integrable on measurable space. Does it have association with my case?

Comment: What is $x$ in the formula for $\mathbb{P}(T>k)$?

Comment: @Mark sorry for my typo. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ is non negative it is sufficient to show that it has finite expectation. Using the tail formula:

$\mathbb{E}[T]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}(T>k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}<\infty$